# wireless sensor network integration with GIS

Tags: qgis

I am working on a project in which I need to represent data on a map after collecting it from wireless sensors.The wireless sensors are placed in the field and it collects information regarding soil ph,moisture,temperature.It is fitted with a gps which takes the co-ordinates.These attributes are then transferred to a computer in the form of an excel sheet.

I want to know if it is possible to take this data directly into Qgis via  a pen-drive,bluetooth etc and plot it on the corresponding map and show the co-ordinates from where the data has been collected

Comment: You can send all the data to the data base like PostGgresql/PostGIS and the fetch at any time then you will get updated data

Comment: can you please elaborate on it..a step by step guide will be helpful